# How to use setter dependency injection on entity

Tags: php, symfony, dependency-injection

I wish to use setter injection on my article entity, but I'm new to this and don't understand it too well.

My error is:

```
My\NewsBundle\Entity\Article
Fatal error: Call to a member function addArticle() on a non-object
```

This happens here in my article entity:

```
/** Inject service: search */
protected $search;
public function setSearch(Search $search)
{
    $this->search = $search;
}

/** @ORM\PostPersist */
public function postPersist()
{
    // wrong: does not have id yet for prePersist; changed to postPersist
    //$search = new \My\NewsBundle\Entity\Search();
    echo get_class($this->search);
    $this->search->addArticle($this);
}
```

FYI: my config.yml has:

```
# Parameters
parameters:
  search.class:  My\NewsBundle\Entity\Search
  google.class:  My\NewsBundle\Entity\Google
  flickr.class:  My\NewsBundle\Entity\Flickr
  article.class: My\NewsBundle\Entity\Article

# Servers
services:
  search:
    class:       %search.class%
  google:
    class:       %google.class%
  flickr:
    class:       %flickr.class%
  article:
    class:       %article.class%
    calls:
      -          [setSearch, [@search]]
```

FYI: I'm running a ContainerAwareCommand and that consumes a feed; extract from Feed entity:

```
        $article = $em->getRepository('MyNewsBundle:Article')->findOneBy(array('feed'=>$this->getId(), 'link'=>$item->link()));
        if (!$article) {
            $article = new \My\NewsBundle\Entity\Article();
```

Any advice on how setter injection works or how to get that service in my entity would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I suggest you reconsider how you manage your code. Entity classes are designed to be POPOs (to manage very basic setter/getter functionality). What you're trying to do fits more into a entityManager type of class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Entities are not managed nor created by the service container. Doctrine is responsible for translating database results into entities.

If you want to inject search service to your Article entity you have to do it manually. As it's rather an optional dependency (you inject it with a setter) you should also check if it's not null in your (post|pre)Persist hook.

Example:

```
$article = $em->getRepository('MyNewsBundle:Article')
    ->findOneBy(array('feed'=>$this->getId(), 'link'=>$item->link()));

if (!$article) {
    $article = new \My\NewsBundle\Entity\Article();
}

$article->setSearch($this->get('search'));
```

Comment: If you switch to a separate event listener rather than a lifecycle callback then that can be a service which you can manage with the container. There is more information on this in this cookbook article http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/cookbook/doctrine . This will also move the responsibility for indexing the article out of the article itself, as well as being reusable if you want to index other entities

Comment: @RichardMiller just a heads up that the link is 404

Comment: I understand now. Thanks kuba. @RichardMiller, thank you very much for your time. I shall definitely consider and look into event listeners, definitely a good option and maybe what I'm looking for since I'm not modifying any properties on my entity with my lifecycle callbacks.